# How would i make the buttons pressed in my calculator show up in my dynamic text box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a calculator with a dynamic text box, buttons from 0-9, and +,-,/,*,=, and clear button. but for some reason everytime I press the buttons on my calculator, they don't show up in my dynamic text box like I need them to. My problem specifically is how do I make it that when the number buttons on my calculator are pressed, the numbers show up in my dynamic text box, like a proper calculator. I would really appreciate your help.
Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var numbers:Array= [btnNum0,btnNum1,btnNum2,btnNum3,btnNum4,btnNum5,btnNum6,btnNum7,btnNum8,btnNum9];

var operations:Array = [btnAdd_,btnSubtract_,btnMultiply_,btnDivide_,btnEqual_,btnClear_];

var o:String;

var number1:Number;

var number2:Number;



function addListeners():void

{
for(var i:uint = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    numbers[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressNumber); 
}
for(i = 0; i < operations.length; i++){
    operations[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pressOperations); 
}
btnClear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearAll);
btnDot..addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addDot);

}

function pressNumber(event:MouseEvent): void
{

// find name of button pressed
var instanceName:String = event.target.name;
// get the number pressed fom the instanceName
var getNum = instanceName.charAt(6)

if(output.text == "0"){
    output.text = "";
}
output.appendText(getNum);
}



function pressOperations(event:MouseEvent): void
{

var instanceName:String = event.target.name;
var  currentOperator:String;


currentOperator = instanceName.slice(3,instanceName.indexOf("_"));
trace(currentOperator)
}

function clearAll(event:MouseEvent): void
{
output.text = "";
number1 = NaN;
number2 = NaN;
}

function addDot(event:MouseEvent): void
{
if(output.text.indexof(".") == -1){
    output.appendText(".");
}
output.text = "0";
addListeners();
}
```

Comment: output.text = "0"; and addListeners(); are into yout function addDot. Thats the reason why your code doesn't work. You made some other errors : "btnDot..addEventListener" ... "indexof" ... "btnClear_ or btnClear?". Your should do that : File > ActionScript settings > 'Strict mode' and 'Warning mode'.

Answer (score 0):

To use property "name" you must set this property after creating instance. Like this:

```
var btnNum0:Button = new Button();
butNum0.name = "btnNum0";
```

If you don't do this "name" property will be empty that looks like your case.

**UPDATE:**

Helloflash is right in his comment to question. At first time I did not see that but in code more mistakes than I thought.

First of all you need to put off your init code from function addDot() to the begining of the code. At now this code will be never called because you try to add listeners into listener addDot().

```
output.text = "0";
addListeners();
```

Also change `indexof` to `indexOf` and remove extra dot from statement `btnDot..addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addDot);`. And big advice/request: use some formatting rules when you write a code (specially about brackets). Your code will be more clean and readable.

Comment: I changed up my code a little, but I still cant get the results im looking for. when I press the buttons their suppose to be seen in my output dynamic box, but they dont come up. I think the problem has to do with my Dynamic box, because when i changed my dynamic box to a label, everything worked. when using the dynamic box and testing the calculator, this shows up in the output beside the compiler: Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to store information in the instance name.  Use objects stored in arrays for the buttons.  This is how you can handle everything like this.

Using objects stored in arrays to handle your buttons, the basic code to make a new button and set its properties (store information about the button in the instance):

```
var aButtons:Array = new Array();var i: int = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var mcButton: McButton = new McButton();
  mcButton.iButtonValue = i;
  mcButton.sButtonName = "Button Number " + i;
  aButtons.push(mcButton);
}
```

Then you can reference the buttons by

```
aButtons[i]
aButtons[i].iButtonValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You have first to set a value to your text field, because `appendText()` method can't append text to an empty text field (nothing will appear).

At the begining of your code:

```
output.text = '0';
```